# Returns installments of an array in full (string) - PHP

Tags: php

I have several installments in a array and I want to completely return, briefly, the number of installment and the values in a string.

**Example**

*Entry of R $ 15.00 + 3 installments of R $ 15.00*

In this test code, it was not possible to obtain this result using foreach.

**how can I do this?**

```
<?php

    $installments = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
        $installments[$x]['installment'] = $x + 1;
        $installments[$x]['value'] = 15.0;
    }
    $policy['installment'] = $installments;
    $policy['in_full']     = get_in_full($installments);

    function get_in_full($installments) {
        foreach ($installments as $installment)
        {
            return 'result';
        }
        //return '1 of $ 15.00 + 3 installments of $ 15.00';
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($policy);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

[image]

Comment: firstly, change `for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {` to `for ($x = 0; $x < count(installments); $x++) {` so it's not hard coded.

Comment: This is not what I need, because I cannot change that, as there is a very large function in production and that I recover the results in this way!

Comment: Are all the installments the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have built this to allow for multiple installments of different values (you don't need to use this),

```
<?php

$installments = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
    $installments[$x]['installment'] = $x + 1;
    $installments[$x]['value'] = 15.0;
}

$policy['installment'] = $installments;
$policy['in_full']     = get_in_full($installments);

function get_in_full($installments) {
    $total = '1 of $ ' . $installments[0]['value'];
    $installmentArray = [];

    foreach ($installments as $installment)
    {
        if ($installment['installment'] != 1) {
            $installmentArray[$installment['value']] += 1;
        }
    }

    asort($installmentArray);

    foreach ($installmentArray as $value => $numberOfInstallments) {
        $total .= ' + ' . $numberOfInstallments . ' installments of $ ' . $value;
    }

    return $total;
    //returns '1 of $ 15.00 + 3 installments of $ 15.00';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($policy);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Adding,

```
$installments[4]['installment'] = 5;
$installments[4]['value'] = 20.0;
```

Gives,

```
Array
(
    [installment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [installment] => 1
                    [value] => 15
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [installment] => 2
                    [value] => 15
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [installment] => 3
                    [value] => 15
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [installment] => 4
                    [value] => 15
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [installment] => 5
                    [value] => 20
                )

        )

    [in_full] => 1 of $ 15 + 1 installments of $ 20 + 3 installments of $ 15
)
```

Comment: this part of the code is giving this error Undefined offset: 15 
`$installmentArray[$installment['value']] += 1;`

Comment: Have you changed the code in any way from the answer? This is written using php 7.3 for reference. Are you able to double check the contents of $installmentArray?

Comment: I used exactly the same code and did not change it, just as I am using the most current version of PHP. returned in $installmentArray `Array ( [15] => 3 )`